# Number of MC Simulations in Multivariate Model with Copulas

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, copula

I am working on a project with the following characteristics:

- 4,000 hydroelectricity generation time series
- 800 futures time series (each corresponding to at least one hydroelectricity time series)
- Each of the above is fitted to its own statistical distribution (resulting in 4,800 processes)
- t-distribution copulas describe the generation series (based on Pearson correlation)
- t-distribution copulas describe the futures series (based on Spearman correlation)

The goal is to obtain the 5th percentile of the expected revenue in such a system via Monte Carlo simulation, such that revenue is the sum of revenues at each hydroelectricity generation, where revenue at each system is the product of hydroelectric generation and the price of the respective futures.

My question is: how many simulations are enough, given the copula structure and the number of variables in play? The resources I've encountered on the web address cases far simpler than mine, and even their estimates vary wildly, so I was hoping your kind expertise could help.

Thank you!

Comment: One thing you may do is monitor how the estimates of your percentile change as your number of simulations grows. You run several independent simulations and see when the estimates are pretty much the same. A good number of simulations will generate stable (not much variance) and accurate (almost the same value) estimates of your percentile.

Comment: This is actually a really good idea. I was hoping there would be some formula that determines the minimum number of simulations based on the number of variables (running the exercise for 250,000 simulations took about a week), but this seems reasonable enough. A colleague of mine recommended a few minutes ago using 0.1 * 4,000 * 800 = 3.2 million simulations, reasoning that 10% of the product should be sufficiently representative of the overall population. Would you agree? Thanks!

Comment: 3.2 million may be enough, but you really should run more than one simulation because you can spot differences that are not noticeable in a single run, specially with percentiles that may be a little tricky relying on low probability events. If you have the time and the computing power,  I would begin by running less simulations 3 or 4 times and see how the estimates behave. Your main constraints are time and computing speed!

Comment: It definitely looks that way. Now that I think about it, the case above corresponds to a situation in which I am looking one day ahead (each price simulation is actually a net change in price) -- would that mean that for, say, a 10-day simulation, I would need to draw 10 random samples from the simulations N times until I can get a distribution? Is it alright if some of the samples overlap? (I have made sure that the data are stationary based on AD Fuller.)

Comment: From what I understand, if you want a 10-day estimate you would have to simulate 10 periods of each time series N times and keep the 10th observation if you are only interested in the 10-day estimate. Samples overlapping is a desirable behavior in Monte Carlo simulations because if samples don't overlap, then they are not exploring the same distribution.

Comment: So, to use the 3.2 million example, I would actually have to actually simulate 32 million data points? How does drawing, say, 10 samples from the 3.2 million differ from drawing 1 sample from each of 32 million? Each column corresponds to a stochastic process that describes a stationary time series (either generation or futures daily price change), with one simulation corresponding to each row, such that each column has its own marginal distribution, and a t-Copula combines them into a single joint distribution based on a Spearman correlation matrix. Does that make a difference?